# NSwagStudio and Swagger 2.0 x-sub_types

Tags: c#, nswag, nswagstudio

I think this is a NSwag or NSwagStudio question, but I'm not experienced enough with it to know if I'm using it wrong, or if there's a bug in NSwag or a problem with the Swagger 2.0 document I'm consuming.

I'm using NSwagStudio 13.6.1.0 to generate a C# client for the Salesforce OCAPI Shop API. The type representing the `order_search_request` property `query` comes out as an empty class with no properties. But the Swagger doc declares several subtypes of `query`, some of which do have properties:

```
  "query": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/query",
      "description": "The query to apply",
      "x-sub_types": {
          "nested_query": "#/definitions/nested_query",
          "filtered_query": "#/definitions/filtered_query",
          "text_query": "#/definitions/text_query",
          "match_all_query": "#/definitions/match_all_query",
          "term_query": "#/definitions/term_query",
          "bool_query": "#/definitions/bool_query"
      }
  }
```

At first I assumed that these `x-sub_types` were supposed to be generated as subclasses of `Query`, which they aren't. But based on the non-Swagger docs for what the request body is supposed to contain, it appears that `Query` is supposed to *have* one of these subtypes, not *be* one of them:

```
{ 
   "query" :
   { 
      "text_query": { "fields": ["customer_email"], "search_phrase":"example@non.existing.com" }
   },
   "select" : "(**)",
   "sorts" : [{"field":"customer_name", "sort_order":"asc"}]
}
```

Since NSwag generates partial classes, I might be able to add the necessary fields to `Query` myself. But is that really the best solution? I'd like to know if it's possible to make NSwag do the right thing in the first place, or if the Swagger doc describes the API incorrectly. Another distinct possibility, especially considering the `x-` prefix, is that `x-sub_types` is just some non-standard thing that Salesforce invented.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, manually adding the "subtype" properties to my own partial of the generated `Query` class works as expected. I still don't know if this is "the" answer, though. There might be a way to customize NSwag to handle this. (`SalesforceServices.OCAPI.Shop` is the package name I gave the generated client.)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SalesforceServices.OCAPI.Shop
{
    public partial class Query
    {
        [JsonProperty("text_query", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Text_query TextQuery { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("match_all_query", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Match_all_query MatchAllQuery { get; set; }
        // TODO all the query types!
    }
}
```